# Opening Chrome App from website (without extension)

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to open a chrome app (this one here- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text/mmfbcljfglbokpmkimbfghdkjmjhdgbg) from a link/button within a website.

I have found similar posts about this topic but the answers say you need to make your own extension. I have seen in another post that you could use chrome.management.launchApp but I believe that this requires you to make your own extension.

My questions are -

1-Is it possible to do this without an extension

2-If not, is there an extension that is already out there

3-How would you implement a link to a chrome app within a website

I am sorry if my knowledge on this topic is a bit basic as I usually stick to html and css.

Comment: From what I have read on other posts url_handlers will only work if you own the chrome app you are trying to link to.

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-launchApp). strangely only works when your on `chrome.google.com/webstore`

Comment: I just found their [github](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/text-app) maybe ask them if they have that feature or ask them if they could implement it. They would have to implement something like [this](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/externally_connectable)

Comment: Do you know how to add chrome.management.launchApp(mmfbcljfglbokpmkimbfghdkjmjhdgbg) to a website with JS ect?

Comment: Take a look at my other comment. I think they have to register it for it to be opened. Yeah I just check the file and they would have to implement it. maybe create a feauture-request? :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, it seems that there is no easy way to implement it myself and I may have to admit defeat on this one

Comment: Awh, you could go and ask them. For what do you actually need an editor.